# How do you return the user Id with a generic repository method in entity framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I want to return the key field by doing something like this:

```
public virtual int InsertWithReturnId(TEntity entity)
        {

            dbSet.Add(entity);
            return entity.Id;
        }
```

Many thanks

EDIT #1:

I dont need a save changes... it's done like this:

```
    public GenericRepository<Group> GroupRepository
            {
                get
                {

                    if (this.groupRepository == null)
                    {
                        this.groupRepository = new GenericRepository<Group>(context);
                    }
                    return groupRepository;
                }
            }
```

My pulling (stores successfully the group)

```
public class GroupMethods
    {
        private UnitOfWork uow;
        public GroupMethods() { this.uow = new UnitOfWork(); }
    public int createGroup(string groupName)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(groupName);
                Debug.WriteLine(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName());
                ApplicationUser user = ClanMethods.getUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserName());

                if(groupName != "" && user != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("inside if");
                    Group grp = new Group();
                    grp.creator = user;
                    grp.Members.Add(user);
                    grp.GroupName = groupName;
                    var id = uow.GroupRepository.InsertWithReturnId(grp);
                    uow.Save();
                    Debug.WriteLine("id:"+id);

                    Debug.WriteLine("stops here");
                    Debug.WriteLine("grp id:"+grp.GroupId);
                    return id;
                }
                return 0;
            }
}
```

I was hoping I could do grp.GroupId but it keeps failing, so I guess not. Will update on interface in 20 mins

EDIT #3

I am getting:

```
Warning 1   Type parameter 'TEntity' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'gdfinal.DAL.GenericRepository<TEntity>'
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>.Add(TEntity)' has some invalid arguments
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'TEntity [....\DAL\GenericRepository.cs(16)]' to 'TEntity'  
Error   4   The type '...chatmodels.Group' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method '....GenericRepository<TEntity>.InsertWithReturnId<TEntity>(TEntity)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from '....Models.chatmodels.Group' to 'gdfinal.DAL.IIdentifier'.
```

when using

```
public virtual int InsertWithReturnId<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : IIdentifier
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
            return entity.Id;
        }
```

It is successfully inheriting the Interface but really doesnt like it :(

Comment: It sounds like you want an interface.

Comment: You mean that your `Id` is an identity-column and you want to return the newly generated ID?

Comment: pretty sure you just need a .SaveChanges() in there.  The id is not assigned until the changes are saved

Answer (score 0):

Make an Interface for your EF object to use.

```
public interface IIdentifier
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your method (and I assume that `TEntity` is a generic argument)

```
public virtual int InsertWithReturnId<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    where TEntity : IIdentifier
{
    dbSet.Add(entity);
    //save changes()?
    return entity.Id;
}
```

If `TEntity` is a generic argument on your class, then add the `where` constraint to the class instead.

Now, because EF auto-generates your classes, use Partials to add the interface (in a separate file)

```
public partial class <NameOfObject> : IIdentifier { }
```

Because the class already has a property called `Id`, you don't have to define it here.

Comment: trying this now, why is it "where TEntity : IIdentity"? thanks

Comment: `where` is a generic constraint, it says that the generic type `TEntity` must impliment `IIdentity`.

Comment: and not where TEntity : IIdentifier?

Comment: Oh wow, missed that, fixed. It's Identifier, not Identity (I've been doing too much sql programming).

Comment: I'm getting errors - please see edit #3. thanks loads for this!

Comment: Don't put the generic argument (`<TEntity>`) in your method, because it must already be defined in your class. Also move the `where` to the class's definition as well.

Answer (score -1):

After SaveChanges(), you can get the id value from a model object like your code (return entity.Id)
So, your code would be like this:

```
public virtual int InsertWithReturnId(TEntity entity)
        {

            dbSet.Add(entity);
            Context.dbSet.SaveChanges();

            return entity.Id;
        }
```

Comment: I think the whole point was "you don't know what the type of `entity` is, it's generic." So you don't know that `entity` has an `Id` field.